# Logout method doesn't delete refresh token from mongo document

Tags: java, spring-boot

So I have a some logout implementation and its supposed to work on next way:

- User click on logout button
- User is redirected to login form
- Refresh token in Mongo document is deleted because every time when user get logged in he gets refresh token and that refresh token has owner id, and that token is stored in mongo document

**What is the problem?**

When I click on logout user is logged out successfully and redirected to login form again but refresh token remain in mongo document.

`This is method to logout user:`

```
@PostMapping("/logout")
public ResponseEntity<?> logoutPage(@RequestBody TokenDTO dto) {

    String refreshTokenString = dto.getRefreshToken();
        if (jwtHelper.validateRefreshToken(refreshTokenString) && refreshTokenRepository.existsById(jwtHelper.getTokenIdFromRefreshToken(refreshTokenString))) {
            // valid and exists in db
            refreshTokenRepository.deleteById(jwtHelper.getTokenIdFromRefreshToken(refreshTokenString));
            return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
        }

        throw new BadCredentialsException("invalid token");

    }
```

`This is refreshToken repository:`

```
public interface RefreshTokenRepository extends MongoRepository<RefreshToken, String> {
void deleteByOwner_Id(ObjectId id);

default void deleteByOwner_Id(String id) {
    deleteByOwner_Id(new ObjectId(id));
}
}
```

This is from `WebSecurityConfig` where I also have some log out config:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(accessTokenEntryPoint).and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll().and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/api/auth/loginAndRegisterForm")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .clearAuthentication(true)
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/api/auth/loginAndRegisterForm")
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .permitAll();

    http.addFilterBefore(accessTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

If I need to provide something else to anyone that is willing to help I'm here, lost a couple of hours but still didn't find nothing inside my code or somewhere on the internet

Comment: You have [tag:spring-security]! Who allowed/advised you to overwrite (built-in) log(/-in)out-controller!?  (It does (probably!) (many) important things, you didn't consider...)

Comment: "For this very purpose, Spring provides the LogoutHandler interface" src: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-logout-handler

Comment: [Official, current doc:](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/logout.html) ...

Comment: Thank you for helping and advices. Btw I was following some tutorial about log/reg authentication and there it is. Btw, can I somehow delete user refresh token even I use provided LogoutHandler interface by Spring?